# How to count checked checkboxes (not in itemgroup)

Tags: html, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap-3

i have a question. Did not found answer before, or it wasn't exacly my problem.

I'm building static app, and i need to have table like this on the page. (They are just binded in the angular... I'm new in it and i have stuck.

```
<table class="table table-responsive table-striped">
  <thead>      
    <tr>
        <th class="text-center"></th>
        <th class="text-center">1st</th>
        <th class="text-center">2nd</th>
        <th class="text-center">3rd</th>
        <th class="text-center">4th</th>
        <th class="text-center">5th</th>
        <th class="text-center">6th</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>First header</td>
      <td class="text-center"><input type="checkbox" ng-model="myModel.myData[1].attribute1" /></td>
      <td class="text-center"><input type="checkbox" ng-model="myModel.myData[1].attribute2" /></td>
      <td class="text-center"><input type="checkbox" ng-model="myModel.myData[1].attribute3" /></td>
      <td class="text-center"><input type="checkbox" ng-model="myModel.myData[2].attribute1" /></td>
      <td class="text-center"><input type="checkbox" ng-model="myModel.myData[2].attribute2" /></td>
      <td class="text-center"><input type="checkbox" ng-model="myModel.myData[2].attribute3" /></td>
    </tr>
```

And it goes further... (ie. myModel.myData[3] (with 3 attributes), myModel.myData[4] (with 3 attributes) , myModel.myData[5] (with 3 attributes) )

Now... i have to count:

- How much attributes1 (with whole myModel.MyData[1 to N]) are selected
- How much attributes2 (with whole myModel.MyData[1 to N]) are selected
- And so on...

All i got now, that i can accces to the value, by: {{ myModel.myData[1].attribute1 }}
But it returns me true/false (that is good) - but can't acces to this in controller. (My controller js file is almost clear, so i don't put it here)

If some1 could help me, where i can search solution i would be thankfull.

Comment: in controller, you can create array with {attributrType, count} by traversing the myModel.myData in loop and check status of checkbox.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look this:

when checkbox is clicked, this call the function for populate array with data of this. After you can get lenght of array using lenght.

```js
var app = angular.module('StarterApp', []);
app.controller('AppCtrl', function($scope){
    $scope.myModel = {myData1: [],  myData2: [], myData3: []};

    $scope.getChecked = function(){
        console.log($scope.myModel.myData1);
        console.log($scope.myModel.myData2);
        console.log($scope.myModel.myData3);
    }

    $scope.toggleSelection = function (data, value) {
        var idx = data.indexOf(value);
        // is currently selected
        if (idx > -1) {
            data.splice(idx, 1);
        }
        // is newly selected
        else {
            data.push(value);
        }
    };
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>

<table ng-app="StarterApp" ng-controller="AppCtrl" class="table table-responsive table-striped">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th class="text-center"><button type="button" ng-click="getChecked()"> Get checked </button></th>
      <th class="text-center">1st</th>
      <th class="text-center">2nd</th>
      <th class="text-center">3rd</th>
      <th class="text-center">4th</th>
      <th class="text-center">5th</th>
      <th class="text-center">6th</th>
      <th class="text-center">7th</th>
      <th class="text-center">8th</th>
      <th class="text-center">9th</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>
        First header
      </td>
      <td class="text-center">
        <input type="checkbox" ng-click="toggleSelection(myModel.myData1, 'check1')"/>
      </td>
      <td class="text-center">
        <input type="checkbox" ng-click="toggleSelection(myModel.myData1, 'check2')"/>
      </td>
      <td class="text-center">
        <input type="checkbox" ng-click="toggleSelection(myModel.myData1, 'check3')"/>
      </td>
      <td class="text-center">
        <input type="checkbox" ng-click="toggleSelection(myModel.myData2, 'check1')"/>
      </td>
      <td class="text-center">
        <input type="checkbox" ng-click="toggleSelection(myModel.myData2, 'check2')"/>
      </td>
      <td class="text-center">
        <input type="checkbox" ng-click="toggleSelection(myModel.myData2, 'check3')"/>
      </td>
      <td class="text-center">
        <input type="checkbox" ng-click="toggleSelection(myModel.myData3, 'check1')"/>
      </td>
      <td class="text-center">
        <input type="checkbox" ng-click="toggleSelection(myModel.myData3, 'check2')"/>
      </td>
      <td class="text-center">
        <input type="checkbox" ng-click="toggleSelection(myModel.myData3, 'check3')"/>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Yes, i did something like this. Althought my controller function looked differently, the idea was good. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If you need the count in your controller, then i guess you need to loup through the checkboxes. As in

```
$scope.attribute1Counter = 0;
angular.forEach($scope.myModel.myData, function(data){
    if(data.attribute1 === true){
       $scope.attribute1Counter++
    }
});
```

Answer (score -1):

Pull underscore.js into your project and use _.where (http://underscorejs.org/#where) to get the count in your controller.

Comment: Please do not use the answer to comment on questions. Instead answer the question or wait for your 50 rep which you will get fast if you provide good answers.